# Stuck Tezos transaction

Tags: transactions, ledger, tzstats

please bear with me being rather new to crypto. I moved a small amount of Tezos from an exchange to my Ledger. Transaction: ongcQGWeFkgda5vkdYjufXfBnoiXiHvEvnXyvVeNcXyGdNhhMKC appears as completed ( confirmations 100+ ). My receiver account appears credited on TzStats but the actual Tezos did not reach my Ledger wallet. Could you be as kind as to tell me how to resolve the issue. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Ledger's central service node (where it fetches balances) is out of sync with the network. If you've confirmed that operation has completed then your funds are indeed safe in the ledger address. It is simply that the Ledger Live application's node is out of sync.

https://status.ledger.com/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did hit the synchro button a lot ( ... ) , when and following whose and indeed what type of action would you say the two Tezos balances will line up?

Comment: Inoticed that ledger status was not 100% healthy these last couple of days https://status.ledger.com/ might that be what causes out of synch ssues?

Comment: @Roy Tezos just completed a network upgrade on Nov 12. If Ledger did not upgrade their software, then their systems and services will be out of sync until they do. Please mark the answer accepted if all is good.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem. Withdrawal completed. I can see it on the blockchain credited to my wallet but is not showing on my ledger. Can see tezos is out of sync on ledger. Should be safe as you say but very anxiety inducing until I see it there on the ledger!

Comment: I also tried to clear cache from Settings - Help on Ledger Live, to uninstall and re-install both Tezos account and App..... Still stuck. Ledger support service does not seem to respond to the ticket placed. Perhaps we could access our Tezos through a different wallet or device? any ideas folk? How would we get about doing that? TY